# Map variable before executing Apollo mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/3-mutations-creating-links/) to get a React app running with Apollo.

Right now I'm in the step of running a mutation, which I have successfully done but I'm trying to perform a more complex one.

So, one of the fields expected in this mutation is a relation one, expecting a **connect** dataset, which has to be something like:

```
tags: {
  connect: [{
   id: "cjoo9e0eq004d0824nibmtzl2"
  },
  {
   id: "cjoopece2000a0899n8jsjkr4"
  },
  {
   id: "cjozmqfal00040878t7huvb2s"
  },
  {
   id: "cjozmsquv000l0878y7t2zccm"
  }],
},
```

For this tags field, on the frontend I'm showing a select multiselect, so the value is going to be an array of ids: ["cjoo9e0eq004d0824nibmtzl2", "cjoopece2000a0899n8jsjkr4"...].

Since the mutation is expecting that field to be an array of objects with ids I'm trying to somehow map that string to transform it into the expected format, but I haven't had any luck. I don't know where can I transform that variable before the mutation gets executed.

Seems like a tricky issue to explain, I hope the explanation is clear enough.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Edit to add some code:

```
const CREATE_VIDEO_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CreateVideoMutation($title: String!, $tags: [TagWhereUniqueInput!]) {
    createVideo(
      data: {
        title: $title, 
        tags: {
          connect: $tags
        }
      }
    ) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`

class CreateVideo extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    tags: [],
  }

  render() {
    const { title, tags } = this.state;
    return (
        .....

      <select multiple 
        className="mb2" 
        value={tags}
        onChange={e => {
          this.setState({ tags: [...e.target.options]
            .filter(({selected}) => selected)
            .map(({value}) => value) })
        }}>
        {tagsToRender.map(tag => {
          return (
            <option key={tag.id} value={tag.id}>
              {tag.name}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </select>

      <Mutation 
        mutation={CREATE_VIDEO_MUTATION} 
        variables={{ title, tags }}
        onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>
        {createVideoMutation => <button onClick={createVideoMutation}>Submit</button>}
      </Mutation>
```

Comment: Do it in the call to the mutation. `props.myMutation({ variables: tags: {connect: arrOfIds.map(id => ({id}))}})`

Comment: hey Kyle, thanks for your answer! the variables are passed to the mutation in the Mutation component: https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/3-mutations-creating-links/
so I don't call the mutation passing the variables. that's the problem...

Comment: `<Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION} variables={{ description, url }}>
  {postMutation => <button onClick={postMutation}>Submit</button>}
</Mutation>` Don't you define your variables right there? I've never used this, but it looks like you would do what I posted above inside the mutation component you define.

Comment: I do, the variable that come from the state: const { tags } = this.state;
I don't see how can I map the tags one before the mutation call gets done

Comment: Post the code for your mutation component as well as the component containing the state you're using, please. We'll get it figured out.

Comment: thanks again for your answer Kyle, I've updated my question adding the code that I think is necessary for a better understanding. I didn't want to copy/paste my whole code since it's more than 150 lines. I hope that piece of code is enough. cheers :)

Comment: if my answer doesn't solve it, I may need to see the definition for `TagWhereUniqueInput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do it.

```
const _tags = tags.map(tag => ({id}))

<Mutation 
    mutation={CREATE_VIDEO_MUTATION} 
    variables={{ title, tags: _tags }}
    onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>
    {createVideoMutation => <button onClick={createVideoMutation}>Submit</button>}
  </Mutation>
```

Comment: I did something quite similar before and it didn't work... I'm gonna try again

Comment: May I see what `TagWhereUniqueInput` looks like

Comment: Just tried your solution and it worked! I think the one I tried before that I said was similar, I didn't send the variables={{ title, tags: _tags }} but variables={{ title, _tags }}.
Anyways. thank you so much, it works :)

Comment: Glad we got it figured out!